# Nexus OSS can't find some artifacts with lucene REST API SHA1 search

Tags: rest, sha1, checksum, nexus, artifact

I am trying to use the restful lucene search feature on nexus oss 2.8.0-05 to find jars in our local repository. It works fine for everything hosted within our repository but seems to have problems searching for artifacts by SHA1 when they are hosted on the central repo and proxied. I have access to another Nexus server and it works fine one that one so I don't know what is wrong.

On our server the following URL returns totalCount=0:

```
http://myserver/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?sha1=51d28a27d919ce8690a40f4f335b9d591ceb16e9
```

But searching for the same artifact but not using sha1 returns results:

```
http://myserver/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=org.sonatype.plexus&a=plexus-cipher&v=1.4
```

Download Remote Indexes is set to True but I think there is something wrong with the index.

Things I have tried:

1. Switching Download Remote Index to false then back to true. I noticed that before I performed this there was no .index file in the central folder but now there is.
2. Updating the index
3. Repairing the index
4. Restarting nexus
5. Checking the connection to the internet and testing with a http proxy (cntlm) to confirm it is not an issue with our ISA proxy.
6. Upgrading from 2.7 to 2.8 and repeating all of the above.
7. Running the scheduled tasks Download Indexes and Rebuild Maven Metadata Files. Both ran in a fraction of a second suggesting they did nothing.

When I repair or update the index it shows the following log message:

> 2014-05-08 05:07:31 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-7] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.NexusScanningListener - Scanning of repositoryID="central" finished: scanned=1121, added=0, updated=0, removed=0, scanningDuration=0:00:42.979

1121 records scanned seems too few for the whole of maven central so I assume it's not updating everything.

Also if I look at System Feeds -> Recent file storage changes in all Nexus repositories then only files in hosted repositories are listed.

I have found someone with a similar problem to me but no solution: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Checksum-search-fails-although-artifact-is-still-there-td5773587.html

Comment: Have you configured a download of the index of the remote repo (especially central) ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like  a communication issue.  The index files on central are gzipped binaries, it isn't uncommon for firewalls to block these.

Have you tried looking in the nexus.log file after running "repair index" against the central proxy?  There should be messages about this failure.